# Is it possible to look at response headers from a video request started via video.js?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js

The media server API I'm using is returning some info I would like to use to better track buffering events, but I'm not sure how to tap into the video request. Is this possible?

Ideally, I am looking for something like this:

```
const player = videojs(videoElement, options);
player.on('serverResponseReceived', (data, headers) => ...
```